# how to downgrade the openGL version up to 2.0 for testing purpose

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am trying to create a software which is compatible with opengl version 2.0 and opengl version 3.2 (core profile). I am using glew to create my context. I have provided a compile time macro to specify the openGl version and I want to test scenerio when maximum openGL version supported is 2.0 and person selects 3.2. My computer supports openGL versions up to 4.5, So I am not able to test this scenario. I want to downgrade the openGL version supported to 2.0 so that I can test this scenario. One way is to use old glew version which supports maximum openGL version 2.0, so that glewIsSupported function will fail for versions > 2.0, but I dont want to change my glew library as this is not proper replication of scenario when the machine really just supports openGL 2.0.

So my question is how can I downgrade my computer to support openGL versions up to 2.0? I want that glew check for 3.2 version support fails, So I can display an error message and stop.

Comment: What kind of errors are you trying to check for? Are you trying to see if you're using stuff from later OpenGL versions? Also, why GL 2.0 and not 2.1? Are there really that many OpenGL implementations that implement 2.0 and not 2.1? Does this have anything to do with the fact that you tagged your question as ES?

Comment: When using opengl 2.0, I am not using VAO and while using opengl 3.2, I am using VAO. This is main difference in code. I need to test this scenario that if the machine only supports 2.0 and the user chooses 3.2, my application will give proper errors and will exit gracefully. It should not give unexpected results and to check that I need to add some test cases. So I need to do this. Is there any way other than downgrading the driver version? Yes i am giving support for opengl es 2.0 and opengl es 3.0 also. So tagged this as es also

Answer (score 0):

Using GLEW to check if your GPU supports newer versions of OpenGL just gets a macro (I.E GLEW_VERSION_4_1)

So where someone might have something like 
`if(!GLEW_VERSION_4_0)` to test compatability, you could just have your own `bool` values that mimic these macros but allow you to 'pretend' your GPU doesn't support newer version.

In theory if you're wanting to test out your functionality when someone does not meet the requirement of OpenGL 3.2 support, you could simply replace where you are querying the supported version with `true` so

```
bool supportOGL3_2 = true;
if(true) //if(!GLEW_VERSION_4_0) replacing this to check that this performs right when unsupported
{
    //Whatever your action is when min req. not met (message box and close application? revert to OpenGL2.0 functionality?)
supportOGL3_2 = false;
    //Example
    AfxMessageBox(_T("GL 4.0 Context not possible. This program requires a newer version of OpenGL. (GL 2.1 and before incompatible). \nPlease check that your GPU supports 4.0 and has an up-to-date driver installed."));
    //Quit app ? then uncomment below
    //ASSERT(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd != NULL);
    //AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd->SendMessage(WM_CLOSE);
}
```

So if you want to revert to using OpenGL2.0 functionality and the fixed-function pipeline, this is where you'd toggle that, for example:

```
//Setup request for OpenGL 4.0 Compatability Profile. Once old Gl is remove, switch this to the first commented line
int attribs[] =
{
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB,   (supportOGL3_2) ? 3 : 2,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB,   (supportOGL3_2) ? 2 : 0,
    //WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB, 
    WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
    0, 0  //End
};
```

This of course will serve the purpose if you're trying to check the display of an error message or some catching functionality, but if you're wanting to actually see what would happen on a GPU that absolutely *cannot* support above GL2.0 but selects a GL3.2 profile; why would you allow this functionality? It would be dangerous practice to allow a system with a below-minimum requirement compatibility to try running your program. The safest bet is to either warn that the application needs GL3.2 supporting hardware, or revert your program to using the legacy OpenGL functionality. If you choose to do the latter, you just need to make that condition in the example code above true to hit that, then make sure to request an older OpenGL context at creation. Nothing fancier would be needed to mimic this, and you shouldn't need to do anything to force your GPU to not support more up to date OpenGL versions.

Comment: What I want is the glew check if the GPU supports 3.2 should fail. So I will give a error message and stop. I need to check this scenario as all the machines I have support 4.5 and glew never fails. I want to downgrade the openGL version so that glew check for 3.2 version will fail. I hope I am being more clear.

Comment: I understand. However other than downgrading your drivers, I am not sure that you can force your GPU to be non-supporting for lower than whatever it supported at factory release drivers. But as I said before, if you are just wanting to check your functionality when older OpenGL only is available, you can mimic this using a if(true) in place of your current glew version check, similar to what I described in the first code segment. I have tested this myself on GPU supporting 4.0 and a GPU not supporting 4.0, using GLEW_VERSION macros provided me with the expected result

Comment: but if you only have GPU's supporting 4.5, you will need to check this with a temporary if statement.

Comment: @PankajBansal Actually, you could confirm that the version checking is working suitable if any of your GPU's only supported something earlier than 4.5 at launch. Then, you **could** roll back your drivers (so that version 4.5 is not supported, only whatever was supported at GPU's launch) and test the catch using GLEW_VERSION_4_5.

I know this does not test the version you want, but it would serve to prove that GLEW is catching the version correctly.

Comment: When using opengl 2.0, I am not using VAO and while using opengl 3.2, I am using VAO. This is main difference in code. I need to test this scenario that if the machine only supports 2.0 and the user chooses 3.2, my application will give proper errors and will exit gracefully. It should not give unexpected results and to check that I need to add some test cases. So I need to do this. Is there any way other than downgrading the driver version?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enforce a downgrading of OpenGL functionality. If you ask for a 2.0 context, the implementation is allowed to give you 4.5 compatibility.

However, you *can* use an [OpenGL loading library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) which supports the ability to expose only the API version you want. These include "glLoadGen" (which I wrote), "glad", and "glbinding". You can use these libraries to generate loaders that will only expose OpenGL 2.0 stuff. That way, even though your implementation supports more, you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/) and get creative with [`MESA_EXTENSION_MAX_YEAR` and `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE`](http://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html):

> MESA_EXTENSION_MAX_YEAR - The GL_EXTENSIONS string returned by Mesa is sorted by extension year. If this variable is set to year X, only extensions defined on or before year X will be reported. This is to work-around a bug in some games where the extension string is copied into a fixed-size buffer without truncating. If the extension string is too long, the buffer overrun can cause the game to crash. This is a work-around for that.
>
> MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE - changes the value returned by
>   glGetString(GL_VERSION) and possibly the GL API type.
>
> ```
> The format should be MAJOR.MINOR[FC]
> FC is an optional suffix that indicates a forward compatible context. This is only valid for versions >= 3.0.
> GL versions < 3.0 are set to a compatibility (non-Core) profile
> GL versions = 3.0, see below
> GL versions > 3.0 are set to a Core profile
> Examples: 2.1, 3.0, 3.0FC, 3.1, 3.1FC
>     2.1 - select a compatibility (non-Core) profile with GL version 2.1
>     3.0 - select a compatibility (non-Core) profile with GL version 3.0
>     3.0FC - select a Core+Forward Compatible profile with GL version 3.0
>     3.1 - select a Core profile with GL version 3.1
>     3.1FC - select a Core+Forward Compatible profile with GL version 3.1 
> Mesa may not really implement all the features of the given version. (for developers only)
> ```